# Changing content using innerHTML with a non-standard element in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml, getelementsbytagname

I have the non-standard element

```
<testele></testele>
```

In every browser except IE, this bit of JavaScript will successfully change the content of the above element

```
document.getElementsByTagName("testele")[0].innerHTML = 'hi';
```

However, if I change the `<testele>` to just a `<span>` (in the HTML and the JavaScript), it now successfully changes the content of the element in every browser, including IE.

Is there any fix? I have searched around and tried a bunch to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'document.createElement("testele");', that will define it in IE?

Comment: Yes, I have, and in multiple ways. It didn't work.

Comment: What about 'var els = document.body.all.tags("testele");'

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work :( I think IE can interpret the element fine, and the problem lies in displaying the content. I know it's possible since Google and Facebook both use it in their "+1" and "like" buttons, but their code is difficult to dissect and it's hard to pinpoint what is doing what. Ugh, this is a really annoying problem.

Comment: I'm open to using something other than innerHTML, too.

Comment: Ok. Wrap that element in a div. Find that div. Do childNodes[0]…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.createElement("testele")` before it is rendered.  This script must be included before the document encouters a `<testele>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/LjwbA/

```
document.createElement("testele");
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("testele")[0].innerHTML = 'hi';
};
```

If you try to do `document.createElement("testele")` after a `<testele>` has been parsed by the browser, it's too late.

Comment: Thanks! I was placing that top line inside the onload function. I'm so happy to finally have this fixed...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [innerShiv](http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/), a Javascript plugin which aims to solve this.

Comment: I would prefer to do it without any plugins, especially jQuery, because this code needs to be as compact as possible.